# Full-Trust Solutions on SharePoint Online Dedicated

Tags: 2010, web-part, 2013, sharepoint-online, application-pages

I am trying deploy a solution to SharePoint Online (SPO), after looking at documentations about SPO, I found only Sandbox Solutions and Apps can be deployed to SPO, but my solution is a Farm Solution.

There are too many limitations in Sandbox Solutions and Apps, such like:

1. Limited access to file system (Application Page);
2. Server side limited access to external data (External Web Service);
3. GAC

Seems all stuffs needs to find workaround to fix.

But I found someone said, you can deploy Full-Trust Solutions on SPO Dedicated, but you need got Certification from SPO (or Microsoft?).

So I checked the list on SPO Dedicated http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn151709.aspx#bkmk_AccessServices , but seems all types of SPO dedicated is NO with Full-Trust Solutions.

So my question is: is that true for we can got this kind certification from SPO? If it is true, could you help give me some information about this? Because I cannot find anything about it on MSDN or other web sites.

PS: If there is good documentation about migrating Farm Solutions to Sandbox Solutions (or Apps), please also share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't deploy farm solutions on spo period.

However you can work around every issue there is with sandbox with using csom and apps.

Take a look here.

http://hughajwood.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/sandbox-solutions-a-necessary-evil/

If it goes down I will update this link.

**UPDATE**
[OfficeDev Patterns and Practices](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP) website is the run to location, also you can use the free code migration assessment tool which is linked from the PnP website.

Comment: Hi Hugh Wood, please check the slide http://www.slideshare.net/aribakker/developing-for-share-point-online, it mentioned Office 365 Dedicated - Farm solutions allowed (requires Microsoft approval). But I can't searched anything with this.

Comment: confirmed with Ari Bakker ‏on twitter:
@zehaozh the slide is for SharePoint 2010 and farm solutions are no longer allowed in sharepoint online dedicated - http://bit.ly/ZrnyAJ

Comment: Sorry missed the notification of your reply. The upside is with the advent of 2013 spo is so much more powerful with apps and CSOM.